# produce a checkmark in FPDF with Line(); instead of making a X

Tags: php, fpdf

so with this code it produces an X

```
$pdf->SetDrawColor(0, 0, 0);
$pdf->SetLineWidth(2.0);
$pdf->Line($x, $y, $x + $w, $y + $h);
$pdf->Line($x, $y + $h, $x + $w, $y);
```

How can I change the two parts that say $pdf->Line();  so I can make it produce a check mark instead?

here this is if it helps aswell

```
if (isset($json->pages[$i]) && isset($json->pages[$i]->areas)) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($json->pages[$i]->areas); $j++) {
      $area = $json->pages[$i]->areas[$j];
      $x    = $area->x;
      $y    = $area->y;
      $w    = $area->width;
      $h    = $area->height;
```

Comment: try  `&#10003;` or  `&#x2713;`

Comment: How would I add that thoug?

Comment: How would I add that into the code?